# Concurrency via Native Extensions on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash-builder

Currently, the AIR beta (3.9) allows concurrency on Android but does not provide it for iOS

To solve this problem, or maybe even to do it more efficiently than AIR workers when they become available on iOS, is it possible to do concurrency via a native extension (ANE)?

I see the section "Threading" at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html but it only leaves me a little more educated at my guessing :)

Let's consider an MP3 Player with visualization. Can an app be built such that the native extension reads the MP3 data, processes it, and hands over both the raw sound data and computed visualization for the actionscript layer to then play/display (and possibly manipulate the display further)?

Comment: Given just how much you are talking about doing with Native Extensions, it makes me wonder if you might be better off writing the app natively than in AIR. While what you are asking for is likely possible, I think it exceeds the scope of what Native Extensions are intended for, which is primarily to access native portions of the OS (such as volume, alerts, notifications, etc)

Comment: Like Josh said, in theory yes. If you are interested in developing visual intensive applications you should go with Obj C, C++, or even Unity. You could also consider using Haxe which compiles to C++, but is written almost like AS3.

Comment: I truly appreciate the advice and I will investigate those routes further, but for this question (and the benefit of others who might land on this page with similar interests but different use cases)- I'd really like to see some code samples/guidance of how [multithreaded file reading+passing the data to flash] would be accomplished using Native Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely think this is a legitimate usage of native extensions. We use threading in a few of the ones we've developed. It's a complex area to create a quick tutorial though but basically the iOS documentation on NSThread is what you should be looking into.

There's a good rundown on the concepts and some sample code here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html

The major difference between this and the AIR concurrency is that the concurrency code is written in AS3 whereas with the native extension you'll have to write in native code for every platform you develop on.